# SQL, Android SQLITE Join

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables which look like:

```
Table A
key1 key2 key3
1    a    a
2    a    a
3    a    a

Table B
key1 key2 key3
1    xxx  zzz
2    yyy  www
```

Now i want to have a big table out of A and B 
where A.key1 matches B.key1 the content of B is pasted 
otherwise if no key1 matches default values are pasted

for example

```
Key1 Key2 Key3 Key5 Key6
1    a    a    xxx  zzz            
2    a    a    yyy  www               
3    a    a    0    0
```

What is the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from a left outer join b on a.key1 = b.key1
```

(this will give nulls for the b columns where there is no matching row from b)

Answer (score 3):

you need LEFT JOIN:

```
select
  a.key1,
  a.key2,
  a.key3,
  ifnull(b.key2, 0) as key4,
  ifnull(b.key3, 3) as key5
from
  tableA a
left join
  tableB b on b.key1=a.key1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select key1, key2, key3, 
    case key5 when null then default(key5) else key5 as key5,  
    case key6 when null then default(key6) else key6 as key6
from a
left outer join b on a.key1 = b.key1
```

### Edit

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d7b4b/4)

```
select a.key1, a.key2, a.key3, 
       ifnull(b.key2, 0) as key5,  
       ifnull(b.key2, 3) as key6
from a
left outer join b on a.key1 = b.key1
```

Comment: if using mysql: where cast(key5 as signed) < 10  if using sqlserver: where cast(key5 as int) < 10

Comment: SQLITE, Android. Won't work with INTEGER. If theres a real value in the cell it works, if 0 because of the ifnull(b.key2, 0) as mentioned below doesnt seem to return a real 0 and the comparision returns nothing

Comment: @user1324936: I don't quite understand your problem. Here is a [SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d7b4b/4). It works for the given table structure you mentioned in your question. Can you modify that example in a way that it doesn't work? After modifying it, post the SQLFiddle link here and I will have a look at the modified example.

Comment: i changed your example a little bit to fit my better to my problem. the cause is the same. the where statement looks on the original table, not on the substitution. Thats why I get an SQLite exception: 1, ambiguous column name: _id when i ask where _id = 0. _id is amiguos for table a and b but not for the concatenated table. have a look here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/64fd4/9

Comment: @user1324936: Now I understand your problem. Can't you just rename the alias like `...as key5_alias`? See this example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/64fd4/14)

Comment: @user1324936: Another possibility for especially your example would be to change the `where` clause to `where key5 is null`. See this [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/64fd4/15)